# What is the difference between these two word in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, libraries

I am trying to get the version of jQuery a page is using in an alert. It works perfect:

I use `alert(jQuery.prototype.jquery)`

Now my question is what is the difference between jQuery and jquery words here that are specified before and after prototype.

which one is specified by $.

Comment: Why the downvote here? I feel this is a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global `$` and `jQuery` variables just point to the same function object, they are "aliases". `jquery` is just the name of the property of the prototype object. The two names have nothing to do with each other - they are names of different properties on different objects.

Answer (score 7):

The first is specified by "$", the second is meant to return the jquery version number.

In Chrome console ->

```
jQuery >>> function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}

$ >>> function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}

jQuery.prototype.jquery >>> "1.7.1"
```

Perhaps it would help to note that JavaScript is case sensitive, so jQuery and jquery are two different variables.

Comment: why wont alert(jQuery.prototype.jQuery) work, your answer should have been a comment.

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. `jQuery` and `jquery` are two completely different objects. just like `var a = 1` and `var A=2` would be two completely different variables

Comment: alert(jQuery.prototype.jQuery) works fine for me and says "1.7.1"

Comment: @hackNightly, undefined for me.

Comment: I just opened up a Chrome console on this page and tried it, are you sure you have Jquery included in the page?

Comment: `undefined` for me too @hackNightly Also, if you go to the code source, you'll see that it isn't defined there either. Stack Overflow uses jQuery, so you can use the console on this page.

Comment: Yes, you would certainly need jQuery included on the page for this to be defined. http://jsfiddle.net/wvZJz/

Comment: @hackNightly: The point is the capitalization. jQuery / Jquery / jquery are all different in terms of code. Your fiddle uses `.jquery` and not `.jQuery` like you initially said.

Comment: @pimvdb, I'm not sure what you mean. The fiddle and my original line of code are the same.

Comment: You say something different in your first comment on this answer, but perhaps I'm just nitpicking :)

Comment: Ooooh, I see what you're saying now. In his first comment, it is capitalized. I didn't notice. Mine is as well, and is in fact 'undefined'

Answer (score 3):

The `$` is the same as `jQuery` with a capital 'Q'. The lowercase `jquery` only represents the version number.

It is more commonly written as `jQuery.fn.jquery` or as a property of a constructed jQuery object like `jQuery('div').jquery`.

Comment: you mean jquery is specified for version no. always. and it doesn;t have any other meaning.

Comment: @Mike yes. That is the only meaning.