# Getting multiple value in each javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, each

I have to append a li within a long ul of n number of li's. The position of the lis needs to be 10th, 20th , 30th and so on. This is my code. When I run using static numbers it works fine, but when I run using variable it is not working. The reason is the number is never equal to the variable. What is the mistake in my code, can someone help?

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui', 'domReady!'], function(jquery) {
  jquery(document).ready(function() {

    jquery("ol#list > li").each(function(index) {
      var getXth = '';
      var tenth = 10;
      var str = parseInt(index);
      var getTenth = parseInt(str * 10);
      var b = 8;
      var getXth = parseInt(getTenth, 10) + parseInt(b, 10);

      alert(index);
      alert('this' + getXth);

      //var getXth = parseInt(str) * tenth;
      //var getValTenth = getXth - 2;
      //alert(typeof sum);

      /*index  == 1 || index  == 8 || index  == 18 || index  == 28 || index  == 38 || index  == 48 || index  == 58 || index  == 68 || index  == 78 || index  == 88 || index  == 98 || index  == 108 || index  == 118 || index  == 128 || index  == 138 || index  == 148 || index  == 158 || index  == 168 || index  == 178 || index  == 188 || index  == 198 || index  == 208 || index  == 218 || index  == 228 || index  == 238 || index  == 248 || index  == 258 || index  == 268 || index  == 278 || index  == 288*/
      //index  == (parseInt(getTenth))

      if (index == getXth) {
        jquery('#list > li:eq(' + index + ')').after('<li class="item product product-item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">' + jquery("div.tenth-product-block").html() + '</li>');
      }

      var getXth = '';
      //index +=1;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: its jquery :) code updated

Comment: `var str = parseInt(index);` <-- um index is an integer so why are you doing that? Same with the getXth line....

Comment: I know but nothing was working so was trying to give it a shot

Comment: well without running code that does not work it is hard for us to debug, what is a portion of the html that would correspond to this code.

Comment: @LAW see accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202717/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-word-in-jquery

Comment: And what does "not working" mean exactly? What happens? Any errors in the console?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs `function(jquery) {` <-- probably why it works....

Comment: This is require and I am using variable jquery, does it matters is I use $j, or $ or jQuery or jquery. The things is code is working correctly my values are getting appended corrected, the issue is with the loop.

Comment: WHAT is the issue with the loop?

Comment: Not sure how `index == getXth` will ever be true since it is saying `index == (index * 10) + 8` which is never going to be true.

Comment: Yes yes that is the issue. I am wrong I know. And that what I want you guys to help me. It should be something like if(index  % 10 == 1) { but I am not able to get it.

Comment: So what is the code supposed to be doing? Inserting the code at what points??

Comment: LOL if(index  % 10 == 1) {  worked!!

Comment: I hate the basics of loops :D

Comment: Actually its still breaking, but I think I know now what to do

Comment: @epascarello ah so it is, missed that xD well I feel like a douche xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(index%10 == 1) { 

                    jquery('#list > li:eq('+index+')').after('<li class="item product product-item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">'+jquery("div.tenth-product-block").html()+'</li>');
                }
```

This was my code. As I used after function so it added html after.